# Monster resource from Cthulu Mythos adjusted for D&D

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters, cthulhu-mythos

I want to introduce some monsters from Cthulu Mythos in my campaign, but I have problems finding a good resource on them. I am looking for suggested abilities, general information and art of them. It would be great to see stats/defenses/HP/level too, but that is optional, I can try to do that my self.

The game I am running is 4th ed, but I can adjust if the stats are from other versions.

Comment: Historical note: the Cthulhu mythos was originally included in D&D's core books, [until Chaosium made legal noises and TSR decided that it wasn't worth it to keep printing Mythos material](http://beyondtheblackgate.blogspot.ca/2011/07/elric-deities-and-demigods.html). This, despite the Mythos having entered the public domain already. Hence, there has been some hesitation to print stats for Mythos creatures over the years.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [d20 Call of Cthulu](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786926392) book has 3rd edition statistics for a number of Cthulu monsters. This includes the Elder Gods.

Answer (score 6):

The 3.5 [*Elder Evils*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elder_Evils) book got a [4e conversion](http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4tut/elderevils) that should at least give you a solid place to start.

Many aberrant creatures from the Far Realm are inspired, at least indirectly, by the Cthulhu Mythos. Unfortunately there aren't any particularly large collections of these monsters in one place, so outside *Elder Evils* I think searching the DDI [Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx) and magazine [Archive](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Archive.aspx) are your best bets. Even if you don't have a DDI subscription, they'll let you search and tell you in which physical sources you'll find those entries (if it says "multiple sources," that usually means the entry appeared first in the PHB1 or MM1 but was republished again later).

Answer (score 4):

As BESW rightly points out, aberrant creatures are D&D's take on Mythos. In particular, take a look at illithids (mind flayers), aboleths, tsochar, gibbering mouthers/orbs, various oozes, swordwings. *Dark Sun Creature Catalog* also had a few good ones. I wouldn't recommend *Elder Evils* conversions, as they've been released in the very early days of 4e, when monster design wasn't that well thought out.

Monster design philosophy in 4e is very different to what came before, and at best 3ed sources can be used for inspiration. In addition to the already recommended *Elder Evils* and *d20 Call of Cthulhu*, take a look at *[Lords of Madness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lords_of_Madness)*. It is an in-depths look at aberrations, and is a fantastic book for inspiration. *[Epic Level Handbook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_Level_Handbook)* also had some decent baddies, including the Pseudonatural template.

As a note on designing monsters for 4e, don't base any of their numbers on sources from past editions. For level, always stick close to the level of the party. Base their role (brute/soldier/skirmisher/controller/artillery) on their flavour, and their specialty role (minion/standard/elite/solo) on their function in the encounter. From these, you'll get their hit points and defenses, which can be further tweaked a bit to suit the idea you have.

In general, you're better off starting with an existing creature, aberrant or otherwise, and giving it a different ability or two. Monster themes are a good way of doing just that, and some are a good fit for what you're looking for.

Comment: While Simons answer is exactly what I was looking for, your question made me reconsider if I even need to use Cthulu mythos or research aberrant creatures and their lore more (I have read all info on them in MM1 and MM2, nothing much there). Thank you, I do appreciate your input!

Answer (score 1):

The AD&D 1E [Deities and Demigods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deities_&_Demigods) 1st printing had Cthulhu monsters in it.

Comment: And costs an arm and a leg, if you can find it.

Comment: Indeed, quite true. It's even hard for the pirates to find!